# ¿Cómo agregar un documento PDF a un documento en LyX (LaTeX)?

Tags: pdf, latex, lyx

Estoy utilizando LyX para crear un reporte, y necesitó agregar (cómo anexo) un documento PDF de varias páginas.

¿Hay forma de hacerlo? De ser así, ¿Cómo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es posible, en el Menú `Insertar` > `Archivo` > `Material Externo`.

[image: Menu]

Especificando donde dice `Plantilla` la opción `Páginas PDF`

[image: Dialogo]

Tras unos segundos la previsualización del PDF que hayas importado aparecerá en tu [lyx](/questions/tagged/lyx).

[image: precarga]